# Android IntelliJ sdk version

Tags: android, sdk, intellij-idea, version

I'm using IntelliJ community edition for developing my Android applications. When creating my project I've set it to use **Android v1.5 SDK**, but now I need to change it to **v1.6**. I've digged hard, but couldn't find such option. Is there a way I can achieve it without recreating my project?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Project Structure` | `Modules` | `<Your Module>` | `Dependencies` | `Module SDK`.